# Custom set interval is not working

Tags: wp-cron

I want to published custom post type schedule articles after an hour interval in between if any schedule articles was there need not to be published. I have created a cron schedule which is working in my local but not in dev server.

Below is the code I have added.

```php
function execution_schedule( $schedules ) {
     global $post_type;
     if( $post_type  == 'articles' )
        $schedules['hour'] = array(
                        'interval' => 3600,
                        'display' => __('1 Hour'),
                        );
        return $schedules;

    }
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'execution_schedule' );
```

Any thoughts on that would be greatly appreciated

Comment: That code is telling WordPress what `hour` means if it's specified in a cron job, but there are no cron jobs defined in the code you shared, and for some reason it's being defined conditionally which doesn't make sense. The literal reading of that code is that the hour schedule only exists on articles archives, which means it will never be defined when cron jobs run ( cron jobs run in a separate request ). It's much more likely that your problem has nothing to do with this code, and more to do with how often your dev server gets traffic since cron cant run if there are no visitors